# Nashorn Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function renderServer

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, nashorn, redux

I have strange behaviour of Nashorn with React-redux.
First, I have very simple javascript, which is babelified before deploying (I put here JSX as resulting babelified file is huge):

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var connect = require('react-redux').connect;
var Link = require('react-router').Link;

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps ", state);
    return {options: state.options};
};

var IndexContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        console.log(this.props.options);
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="r">Link!</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Index = connect(mapStateToProps)(IndexContainer);

var renderServer = function (data) {
    var data = Java.from(data);
    return React.renderToString(
        React.createElement(Index, {data: data})
    );
};
```

Second, I have Java code:

```
@Component
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class ReactRenderer {
    private ThreadLocal<NashornScriptEngine> engineHolder = new ThreadLocal<NashornScriptEngine>() {
        @Override
        protected NashornScriptEngine initialValue() {
            NashornScriptEngine nashornScriptEngine = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager()
                    .getEngineByName("nashorn");
            try {
                nashornScriptEngine.eval(read("static/nashorn-polyfill.js"));
                nashornScriptEngine.eval(read("/WEB-INF/resources/js/main.js"));
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return nashornScriptEngine;
        } 
    };

    private Reader read(String path) {
        InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
        return new InputStreamReader(in);
    }

    public String render(List<Object> objects) {
        try {
            Object html = engineHolder.get().invokeFunction("renderServer", objects);
            return String.valueOf(html); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("failed to render react component", e);
        }
    }
}
```

when I invoke render(objects) in java I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function renderServer
    jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:204)
    jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:383)
    jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
```

if I delete

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("mapStateToProps ", state);
    return {options: state.options};
};
```

it does find the renderServer function, but then it fails to eval as no `mapStateToProps` there, and according to redux [tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html) should be rendered to string the whole thing with all props, `Provider` etc., not just `React component`, otherwise handle function using `this.store.dispatch` will not work.
What am I doing wrong here and how to make it work?

---

UPDATED:
I found that the problem is with babelified batch file. If I put to the file I want to evaluate only React components (JS, not JSX) and renderServer function without any libraries, Nashorn is able to find renderServer function and invokes it.
But all the tutorials say Nashorn is perfect in understanding batch files. 
So I really don't understand what's the problem could be.

Comment: What JDK/Nashorn version are you using? There have been problems with running React with Nashorn in earlier JDK8 releases. Maybe try with the latest update release of an [early access snapshot](https://jdk8.java.net/)

Comment: @HannesWallnöfer I use 8u65 Oracle, and I failed to find this kind of error.

Comment: 8u65 should be fine. What do you mean by "batch file"? Nashorn can only handle JS files.

Comment: I mean it's one processed file containing code of all the libraries instead of 'require' or 'import' statements. Sorry, I am a novice in JS, probably there is a word for that file that I confused.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are probably using webpack your var renderServer ends up being local variable within the webpack function.
global.renderServer = .... should work

Comment: Looks like you can be right. Thanks for that. I will return to this code in a while and definitely try.